# Android wear DataApi with different package

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I have several identical apps that just differ on the data they show and package name. I've decided to give Android wear a try and my main goal was to develop a single Android Wear app to show data for every one of my phone apps (maybe with a 2d slider,  one row per each app).

Imagine I have 2 apps:

- Free "com.company.appfree"
- Pro "com.company.apppro"

And the wear app

- "com.company.appwear"

It turns out I was unable to get the DataItems or Messages sent by my phone apps on the Wear app, unless its package was identical to one of the phone apps packages ("com.company.appfree" or "com.company.apppro")

I'd like for someone to tell me if there's a way I could achieve this communication without the need for the apps to have the same package. I really need a single wear app, not multiple ones.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to send data to an app with a different package. Moreover your app will be installed to a wearable device only if the containing app has the same package, so in your case only one app will be able to contain the common wearable part.

I think the only way to make two apps to communicate with a single watch app is to implement the watch app and the corresponding handheld part as a separate app (this app and the watch app will share the package name and will be able to communicate to each other). 
Your other apps on phone can communicate with this one to send data to a watch. This communication can be implemented via broadcasts or service bindings. 
So you will have the following structure:

1. `com.company.wearservice` and the corresponding watch app with the same package.
2. `com.company.app1` and `com.company.app2` send data to `com.company.wearservice`, which sends they to the wearable part.

Answer (score 1):

The package names must match for the wearable app and the phone app to communicate using `DataApi`. In your setup, you won't be able to communicate.

However, this doesn't mean you can't achieve what you want at all. You can setup your apps in the following way:

`com.company.appfree` on the phone

`com.company.appfree` on the wearable

`com.company.apppro` on the phone

Now, add one communication channel:

`com.company.appfree (phone)` <- `DataApi` -> `com.company.appfree (wearable)`

and then, only on the phone, add a `ContentProvider` to `com.company.appfree` and protect it with a permission (make the permission protection level signature, more about this here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html). Now you have following channel of communication:

`com.company.apppro (phone)` <- `ContentProvider` -> `com.company.appfree (phone)` <- `DataApi` -> `com.company.appfree (wearable)`

Comment: It looks like a good solution, but if "com.company.appfree" was ever removed the wear app wouldn't be able to communicate with the other phone apps, right?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that if you remove `com.company.appfree` from the phone, it will also be automatically removed from the wearable. So the situation you are describing (`com.company.appfree` on the wearable and `com.company.apppro` on the phone) won't happen.

Comment: I really don't want to obligate the user to keep the app installed. And since I have more than two apps (related with each other, but not necessarily free/pro) I can't make sure the user installs the one with the wear app. Even if I was to inform the user about this, it just doesn't seem the correct way to achieve it. So I'm accepting @esentov's answer, a centralized app that works like a remote for the other apps looks like a better solution in my case.